# How do I convert a function name into a string

Tags: javascript

I have a function from an object, lets say Object.MyFunc. 
I need to send this function name into another function like so: doSomething("Object.MyFunc");

any advise?

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but in ES6 this ability is provided via the [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property. The [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) defines [how this property is added to a Function instance](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname):

> 9.2.11 SetFunctionName (F, name, prefix)
>
> The abstract operation `SetFunctionName` requires a `Function` argument `F`, a `String` or `Symbol` argument `name` and optionally a `String` argument prefix. This operation adds a `name` property to `F` by performing the following steps: ...

Unfortunately, this hasn't yet been implemented in all major browsers: It's listed [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-function_name_property) as not supported in all IE versions, and only partially supported in all other major browsers (with Edge 13 having the best, albeit still partial, support currently).

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a really good way to get the function name. In JavaScript, you can have anonymous functions and therefore don't have a decent way to name them.

In any case, you might have some luck using `arguments.callee.toSring()`.  For example:

```
function foo() {
    alert("I am " + arguments.callee.toString());
}
```

But, this is poor because not all functions have names and some browsers may append implementation-specific details to this string.

But, perhaps you are trying to do something else besides getting the name? If you want to eventually call the function, you can actually pass the function itself. This is called a lambda function. For example:

```
function foo(inFunc) {
    inFunc();
}

foo(function() { alert("foo"); });
```

The above code creates an anonymous function that pops up an alert. It is then passed to the `foo` function which just calls whatever function is passed into it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to call `MyFunc` from within `doSomething`, you can just pass the actual function:

```
var someObject = new Object();
someObject.MyFunc = function() { alert('test'); }
function doSomething(func) {
    func();
}
doSomething(someObject.MyFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it is most likely that whatever you're trying to do can be done better a different way. However, if you truly need to find the name of a function, there is one fairly simple way to do this, but it will not work in all cases.

```
//returns the name of the function func on the object obj
function getFuncName(obj, func){
  for(var funcName in obj){
    if(obj[funcName] === func){
      return funcName;
    }
  }
}

alert(getFuncName(Object, Object.MyFunc)); //alerts "MyFunc"
```

The limitation here, is that you'll need both the object and the function, and the function will have to be iterable - meaning that it can't be a built in function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean something like this?

```
function getFn(fnName){
    for (var l in yourObj){
      if (l === fnName && yourObj[l] instanceof Function){
        return [ l, yourObj[l] ];
      }
    }
    return [fnName ,'not found'];
}
```

the loop iterates through the object and delivers an array containing the method name and a pointer to the method (or an error message).

Answer (score -1):

If you have this function:

```
function test()
{
  alert('here');
}
```

You can call it in this way:

```
function testTest(func)
{
   func();
}

testTest(test);
```